# XMPP connection is not remaining established after a certain duration

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

I am developing an Instant chat messaging Application using XMPP framework in android. Chat works fine while I am on chat screen. But if I minimize the app i.e If I put the app in the background on receiver end then also chat works fine while I am continuing sending messages. But when I stop sending messages and leaving the app in background on receiver end then after a certain duration may be like 30 mins or an hour if try to send a new message, it stops receiving messages.
I think the reason should be that XMPP connection is getting broken for some reason. Is there any way to mantain the connection for forever so that it never gets broken. Or do we need to run a service in background in order to do that. If yes please tell me the code for doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to select 'Do not disconnect clients that are idle.'
in the connection manager of openfire web admin.
Open your admin console and go to **Server > Server settings > Client connections > Idle connection policy** (http://127.0.0.1:9090/client-connections-settings.jsp). Then select the option 'Do not disconnect clients that are idle'.

In this way, openfire won't disconnect inactive users.